# Why do I get an "Expected a Platform Name" error when building with WebKit on MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit, wkwebview

I've recently updated my build system to macOS 10.15 and Xcode 11.3.1 but when I try to compile one of my programs I get an "Expected a platform name, e.g., 'macos'" error and the build stops.
I've identified that this issue occurs only if I build with WebKit - if I comment out that code then the software builds and runs correctly (with the exception of the ability to display HTML, of course).
I wondered if the issue might be in my use of WebViews - which are deprecated - so I updated the code to WKWebView instead, and the problem still occurs.  Of course, since I am getting this error, I don't know whether I've updated to WKWebView correctly or not - it won't run, and it doesn't show any other fault with this part of my code.

HTMLViewController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import "ReadEML.h"

@interface HTMLViewController : NSViewController //<WebPolicyDelegate>
{
    NSSize dpi; 
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet WKWebView *mailContentView;

- (WKWebView*)contentView;
- (void)displayContentFromReader:(id)emlReader;
- (void)setFormattingOn:(bool)formatting;

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;

@end
```

HTMLViewController.m

```
#import "HTMLViewController.h"
#import "Webtools.h"
#import "Stringtools.h"

@interface HTMLViewController ()

@end

@implementation HTMLViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    CGDirectDisplayID displayID = [_mailContentView.window.screen.deviceDescription[@"NSScreenNumber"] unsignedIntValue];
    CGSize size = CGDisplayScreenSize(displayID);
    CGDisplayModeRef mode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(displayID);

    dpi.width = CGDisplayModeGetWidth(mode) * 25.4 / size.width;
    dpi.height = CGDisplayModeGetHeight(mode) * 25.4 / size.height;
    CGDisplayModeRelease(mode);

    float scaling = [AppDelegate.sharedAppdelegate getPreferenceForKey:@"DefaultZoom"]?[[AppDelegate.sharedAppdelegate getPreferenceForKey:@"DefaultZoom"] intValue]:100;

    [_mailContentView.webFrame.frameView.documentView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(dpi.width / (dpi.width / (scaling / 100.0)), dpi.height / (dpi.height / (scaling / 100.0)))];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    return self;
}

- (WKWebView*)contentView {
    return _mailContentView;
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    if (navigationAction.request.URL) {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        [NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace openURL:navigationAction.request.URL];
    } else {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
}

- (void)displayContentFromReader:(id)dataCollector {
    @autoreleasepool {        
        NSString* pathStem = getTempCacheDirectory();
        NSURL* rootURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[pathStem stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURL* ReadRootURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[pathStem stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [_mailContentView.webFrame loadHTMLString:[dataCollector getContent:@"RawHTML"] baseURL:ReadRootURL];
    }
}

@end
```

My gut instinct tells me that this particular issue isn't in my code - can anyone suggest what else might be going on?  As I say, if I don't import the .h file and I remove all references to its usage in the code then the code compiles without a problem.

It also compiles without a problem on macOS 10.14.

I'm perplexed!

Answer (score 0):

This may help some people with this specific issue - I've found a solution that works for me, but I'm not happy with it because it feels hacky.

Simply add the following define to your header and your code should compile without difficulty.  I'd still be interested to understand why Apple changed this, whether it is intentional or a bug, and what the 'correct' solution should be.

```
#define TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST 1
```